# store variable from javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store a string in to a variable after running a function. When it runs it returns as undefined. At the bottom I have tried adding `return marginDirection;` but it still returns as undefined. I am not sure where I am going wrong. I've gotten stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

`var marginDirection = getMarginDirection();`

```
            function getMarginDirection() {
                if (floatDirection == 'right') { 
                    marginDirection == 'left'; 
                    } 
                else if (floatDirection == 'left') { 
                    marginDirection == 'right'; 
                    } 
                else { 
                    marginDirection == ''; 
                    }
                };
```

Comment: try with `return`. also, that v

Comment: `==` is the *comparison operator*...!

Comment: Because you're setting one variable and returning not-that-variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getMarginDirection()
{
    if (floatDirection == 'right')
        marginDirection = 'left'; 
    else if (floatDirection == 'left')
        marginDirection = 'right'; 
    else
        marginDirection = '';

    return marginDirection;
}
```

`Return` the variable and assign values with `=` not `==`

Comment: excellent. exactly what I was looking for. Silly mistake using == instead of =. I am still new to javascript, thanks for the help! will mark as correct in 12 minutes when I a can.

Comment: Actually, all variables are global by default *(unless declared with `var`)* in javascript, so there is no need to return anything (although it's better to do it).

Comment: @PetrR. That's quite some terrible advice. Variables are not "global by default" unless you forget to *declare them properly* using `var`.

Comment: @deceze That's what global by default means-and simply "using var" isn't enough, they have to be in a function for var to make a difference.

Comment: @Dave If you don't have functions, then "global" doesn't mean anything either.

Comment: @deceze - I'm not saying he should do it. I'm just saying it will work without it. I edited my previous comment to make it more clear.

Comment: @deceze It does if there's any other JavaScript. That side, my point is that the advice wasn't "terrible", it was mildly imprecise, and your follow-up was equally imprecise.